odt-file table - java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc.OdfTextDocument cannot be cast to class org.odftoolkit.simple.Document
I'm trying to search a .odt document file for a placeholder test to replace it and save the file as PDF. It seems to work for regular text, but when the placeholder is inside a table, I get the exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc.OdfTextDocument cannot be cast to class org.odftoolkit.simple.Document (org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc.OdfTextDocument and org.odftoolkit.simple.Document are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

this is the code:
     OdfDocument odt = OdfDocument.loadDocument(templateFile);
            var root = odt.getContentRoot();

            TextNavigation search = new TextNavigation("\\{firstLineItemTitle\\}", root);

            while (search.hasNext()) { //<-- Exception here
                TextSelection selection = (TextSelection) search.nextSelection();
                var container = selection.getContainerElement();
                var parent = container.getParentNode();
                //selection.replaceWith(replacement);
            }

Why does this happen? How can I replace contents of a table and preferably get a reference to the table itself to add more rows.
